# Compare and count most occurring dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Holla!

I have 400 csv files, each with around 50,000 rows (this varies from file to file) and exactly 2 columns. The goal is to find the files which are exactly the same (there might multiple uniquely similar files), but the ultimate goal is to look for the most occurring files with the same data.

The steps I'm trying to implement are listed as follows:

1. importing csv files as pandas df
2. this step is to check the shape of the files/dataframes. If the shapes of the df are same, then I may check the elements for equality) (the ones with different shapes already drops off from the same df consideration)
3. sorting the df based on first column with its corresponding second column
4. taking difference of the sorted dataframes (if the difference results in 0, the df are exactly same, which is needed)
5. store the variable names of the same dataframes in a list

Here is a dummy setup I'm working on:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## step 1.
# creating random dataframes (implying importing csv files as df)
# keeping these three as same files
df_0 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4, 1, 2, 1, 1], 'b': [1, 3, 4, 2, 4]})
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4, 1, 2, 1, 1], 'b': [1, 3, 4, 2, 4]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4, 1, 2, 1, 1], 'b': [1, 3, 4, 2, 4]})

# taking these two as same files
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3, 2, 2, 1, 1], 'b': [1, 3, 4, 3, 4]})
df_4 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3, 2, 2, 1, 1], 'b': [1, 3, 4, 3, 4]})

df_5 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2], 'b': [2, 3, 4, 2, 1]})

#taking a couple of files as different shape
df_6 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2,3], 'b': [2, 3, 4, 2, 1,2]})
df_7 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 2, 1, 2,3], 'b': [2, 3, 4, 2, 1,2]})

###here there are two different sets of same df's, however as described in ultimate 
###goal, the first set i.e. df_0, df_1, df_3 is to be considered since it has most number 
###of (3) same df's and the other set has less (2). 

## step 2. pending!! (will need it for the original data with 400 files)

## step 3.
# function to sort all the df in the list
def sort_df(df_list):
    for df in df_list:
        df.sort_values(by=['a'], inplace=True)
    return df_list

#print(sort_df([df_0, df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4, df_5]))

# save the sorted df in a list
sorted_df_list = sort_df([df_0, df_1,df_2, df_3,df_4]) # this performs: 0-1, 0-2, 0-3, 1-2, 1-3, 2-3

#sorted_df_list = sort_df([df_0, df_1,df_2, df_3,df_4,df_5,df_6,df_7]) # 0-1, 0-2, 0-3, 0-4, 0-5, 0-6, 0-7, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5, 1-6, 1-7, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5, 2-6, 2-7, 3-4, 3-5, 3-6, 3-7, 4-5, 4-6, 4-7, 5-6, 5-7, 6-7


## step 4.
# script to take difference of all the df in the sorted_df_list
def diff_df(df_list):
    diff_df_list = []
    for i in range(len(df_list)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(df_list)):
            diff_df_list.append(df_list[i].subtract(df_list[j]))
            # if the difference result is 0, then print that the df are same and store the df variable name in a list
            if df_list[i].subtract(df_list[j]).equals(df_list[i].subtract(df_list[j])*0):
                print('df_{} and df_{} are same'.format(i,j))
             
    return diff_df_list

## step 5.
#### major help is needed here!!!! #####
# if the difference result is 0, then print that the df are same and store the df variable name in a list
## or some way to store the df which are same aka diff is 0

print(diff_df(sorted_df_list))

# # save the difference of all the df in a list
# diff_df_list = diff_df(sorted_df_list)
# print('------------')
# # script to make a list of all df names with all the values as 0
# def zero_df(df_list):
#     zero_df_list = []
#     for df in df_list:
#         if df.equals(df*0):
#             zero_df_list.append(df)
#     return zero_df_list

# print(zero_df(diff_df_list))
```

As tested, on first 4 df's, the defined functions work well, that results into df_0, df_1 and df_3 as 0's.

I am seeking help to store these variable names of df's that are the same.
Also, the logic should work well for possible exceptions, that can be checked by incorporating all 8 of the created df's.

If anyone may have feedback or suggestions for these issues, that would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

An efficient method could be to [hash the DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71975048), then identify the duplicates:

```
def df_hash(df):
    s = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(df, index=False) # ignore labels
    return hash(tuple(s))

hashes = [df_hash(d) for d in dfs]

dups = pd.Series(hashes).duplicated(keep=False)

out = pd.Series(dfs)[dups]

len(out) # or dups.sum()
# 4
```